# Populate a field based from value of body class value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to populate a field in a form with a class from the body element, which starts "pageid-" and then has a number after it. I would like to find this number, and add it as the form value which enables me to use the same form on every page but identify which page the form was submitted on.

I am still learning Java/JQuery so apologies on not knowing how to return the value here. It's coming in as [object Object] - This is what I have currently:

HTML

```
<body class="pageid-1232">

<input type="text" id="test1" value="">

</body>
```

Javascript

```
var thisid = $('[class^="pageid-"]');

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#test1").val( thisid );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Gg6AG/44/

Comment: may be  $("#test1").val( thisid.className );

Comment: I would recommend to add the value as a data attribute instead of parsing it from the class (that is what this attributes are made for). the body would look like <body class="pageid-1232" data-id="1232">. This way you can have other classes in it. and you can retrieve object data with thisid.data("id")

Comment: @valarauko Sensible suggest dude yeah, hadn't thought of that either but I know data attribute is used more and more now and is very versatile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var thisid = $('[class^="pageid-"]');

$(document).ready(function () {
    var num = $(thisid).attr("class").split("-").pop(); // it will extract the number from class 
    $("#test1").val( num ); // set that number to input field
});
```

Comment: Very nicely done dude, thank you so much. Will choose as answered when I am allowed - hopefully this will be of use to somebody else also! Interesting that you used `.pop()` and `.split()` would never have thought of that :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // converts the classList - an Array-like list of class-names - of
    // of the <body> element/node into an Array; and then filters that
    // Array of class-names using Array.filter.prototype(), to retain
    // only those classes for which the inner comparison return true:
    var classValue = Array.from( document.body.classList ).filter(function(c){
        // 'c' (the first argument of the method) is the
        // array-element of the Array over which we're iterating
        // and is supplied by the Array method.

          // here we return only those class-names that have
          // a string of numbers ('\d+') before the end of
          // string ('$'), using RegExp.test() to return
          // a Boolean, true: the string matches the regexp,
          //            false: the string does not match:
                    return /\d+$/.test(c);

                // here we assume only one matching class-name,
                // and user Array.prototype.join('') to convert
                // that single-element array into a String 
                // and split that class-name on the '-' character:
                }).join('').split('-')
                // and use Array.prototype.pop() to retrieve
                // the last element of the returned Array:
                .pop();

    // finding the element with the id 'test1' and setting
    // its value property to the found-value:
    document.getElementById('test1').value = classValue;
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Gg6AG/507/).

Incidentally the reason that this:

```
$("#test1").val( thisid );
```

couldn't work is because `thisid` is a jQuery Object, and when you try to set a string value by passing an Object (an Object, not an object-property) the JavaScript engine will try to coerce that Object to a String representation, which will generate a value of `[object Object]`, this can be verified with:

```
console.log({}.toString());
```

```js
var obj = {};

document.querySelector('input').value = obj;

console.log(obj.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input />
```

or for a more comparative demonstration:

```
console.log($('body'));
```

```js
var obj = $('body');

document.querySelector('input').value = obj;

console.log(obj.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input />
```

Comment: Thanks David, interesting way of doing it slightly differently. Looks fine on paper there but testing it seems to return no value for me. Perhaps I am missing something though :)

Comment: Sorry didn't see your comments, was too hasty with my reply. Will retest.

Comment: Created a fiddle with it David, not seeing anything returned still oddly http://jsfiddle.net/Gg6AG/505/

Comment: The problem was I rather foolishly used a reserved-word ('class') for a variable *and* I forgot to convert the Array to a String before calling `split()`. Belatedly corrected just now.

Comment: Thanks David, well documented. As the first answer is also correct I think it's fair to stick with it, but this is also a great and thorough alternative solution tested and working great.